# C# Regex expression detect end of line

Tags: c#, regex

I need a C# regex expression that matches on all of these combined -

ABC (and a space and zero or more characters that follows)

ABC (and no space and any *number* that follows)

ABC (and end of line) <- this is the one I can't figure out

This is what I have so far -

```
 bool match = Regex.IsMatch(address, @"((ABC)?[\s+0-9*])");
```

I tried this to no avail (and a bunch of other stuff) -

```
 bool match = Regex.IsMatch(address, @"((ABC)?[\s+0-9*$])");
```

Comment: 1) Tag with a language 2) *Show* what you have done and explain how it doesn't work (this will also provide the appropriate context) - many regular expressions support `$` but the meaning varies, especially if there are single/multiline modes. Things can get trickier if needing to search for "end of line" *and/or* "end of input".

Answer (score 1):

```
/ABC(?: \w*|\d+|\n)/
```

`\n` matches the new line.

Comment: May also use `$` instead depending on the engine, mode, and strings

Comment: Doesn't this case only match a space followed by a newline, and not the newline alone (i.e. it matches `ABC \n` and not `ABC\n`)?

Comment: This matches `ABC\n`, but not `ABC \n`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
/ABC(?: .*|\d+)?$/
```

Comment: Problem with that is it wont match **"ABC2314 some other stuff"**.  Per OP's spec, it should match the **ABC2314** portion.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps, i follow what you are saying, but the OP is not specific on that case.  i read _ABC (and no space and any number that follows)_ to mean ABC followed by ONLY numbers...  technically _some other stuff_ in your example FOLLOWS ABC2314 and hence would disqualify it.  the OP is too vague to definitively say